# HTML gets generated with trailing </param> tags

Tags: html, firefox

I am trying to pass some parameters to an object in one of my webpages.  Here is the source HTML:

```
<object id="Meter" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"type="application/x-silverlight-2"
    draggable="false" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:inline">
<param id="xapSource" runat="server" name="source" value="ClientBin/SmartSwitch_V13.xap" />
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<param id="initParams" runat="server" name="initparams" value="" />
</object>
```

When I build the website and run it in IE 11.0, and view the source, it appears thus:

```
<object id="Meter" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            draggable="false" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:inline">
<param id="ctl00_MainContent_xapSource" name="source" value="ClientBin/SmartSwitch_V13.xap"></param>
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<param id="initParams" name="initparams" value="key1=BOB"></param>
</object>
```

Note how IE 11.0 has added on two < /param > terminating tags to two of the elements ... I can only assume because both had an 'id=' attribute (is this assumption right or wrong?).  But even though there is no HTML reference that I can find that says terminating < /param > tags are legitimate or valid, IE 11.0 still processes the webpage without error.  Well, thanks for that small mercy, IE 11 ....

However, when I try and run the same webpage using Firefox, it refuses to load the webpage and highlights the two tags in red with the message 'Stray end tag /param'.  So I can only assume that Firefox won't load this page until the HTML is perfect for it, i.e. these two tags don't appear.

But my original webpage source does not have them in, so I can only assume they are being generated.  So my question is: how can I change my HTML source so two tags DON'T get generated and the HTML appears perfect for Firefox to load my webpage?

Comment: What doctype are you using? Are you using a webserver or your local computer?

Comment: I am using my local computer (localhost) to test.  Obviously when (if) I get the Firefox load to work, I will publish the changes to the production website (which already works with IE 11 btw)

Comment: Doctype is <!DOCTYPE html> btw

Answer (score 0):

First there is no space between:

```
data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"type="application/x-silverlight-2"
```

Which makes your markup invalid, not sure if that is what is causing the issues.

Comment: Good spot ... but that's a consequence of my poor uploading of HTML into Stackoverflow!  The source actually reads:   x-silverlight-2,"   "type="application     so there IS a space between them even though I can't seem to show it

Comment: @RichardHammond does this work on your firefox? http://bubblemark.com/silverlight2.html

Comment: Yes, it does ... hmmm ... just let me check out the difference between this and mine - thanks

Comment: Ok - the difference(s) are - my HTML has a couple of < param > with an 'id' attribute set in them.  I can only assume the 'id' is (somehow) causing the trailing < / param > tags to be generated ....?

Comment: I think that if you compare the original source with that which IE 11 loads, then the difference is that I lose the   runat = "server"   so I guess that in the process of doing its job, it must be ASP.Net which is generating the trailing < /param > tags.  Or am I talking rubbish??

Comment: I thought you were opening the page as a local file? How would asp.net be relevant to that? Or are you running a local webserver with ASP?

Comment: I am running a local webserver with ASP ... and then when (if ?!?) it works I publish it on my remote website